# OpenSSH Windows Server 2016

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2016, ssh-keygen

I am trying to install OpenSSH on a windows server machine. When i use this command:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*
```

I don't get this output:

```
Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

but it's empty:

[image: OpenSSH Output]

When I do:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

it works, but once I try so start the server:

```
Start-Service sshd
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
```

I get this message error:

> Start-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'sshd'.

Comment: Is your Windows Server on version 1709 or newer?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it's a Windows Server 2016 Standard

Answer (score 2):

[Judging from the Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), it appears that installing Open SSH through PowerShell in this way is a feature of Windows Server 2019 and not of 2016.